# jQuery UI Sortable, how to get DOM element at old position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list that I have made sortable using jQuery UI. What I need to be able to do is access the jQuery object (DOM element) that is now at the original position of the dragged element. How would I go about doing this?

I have the starting index of the dragged element if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, playing with indexes:

```
$(function(){
var startIndex = false;
$('ul').sortable({
    items: ' > li',
    start: function(event,ui){
         startIndex = ui.item.index();
    },
    stop: function(event,ui){
        if(false !== startIndex) {
            $('#result').html('<br />Element on the original place of the moved element: ' + $('li:eq('+startIndex+')').text() + ' ');
        }
        startIndex = false;
    }
});
```

});

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m3cSu/